# What's this certificate mark?

Tags: certification

The bottom row has an ETL Mark, a double insulate, an FCC logo, not quite sure what that little house next to the FCC logo is but what I am most intrigued about is the logo above them, it looks like VI.
[image]

Comment: How about a picture that isn’t blurred.

Comment: Yes, yes, fixed it.

Comment: Next to VI is the voltage and current ratings for the device.

Comment: "6", not "vee-i"

Comment: the little house is "indoor use only"

Comment: just to clarify ... as @Maple commented, that is a Roman numeral VI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CEC Level VI Efficiency standard. More info [here](https://www.digikey.ca/en/articles/techzone/2015/aug/efficiency-standards-for-external-power-supplies)